# Parsehub: Pagination not work on http://eservices.dubaitrade.ae

Tags: parsehub

Im trying to scrap data by pagination but pagination not work on next button below you can see i applied code but it not get data by pagination below is URL please see

http://eservices.dubaitrade.ae/clientdirectory/clientsSearch.do?field=act_desc&d-5437-p=1&buId=181&keyword=trading

I applied click command next page but not go to next page

please tell me how i apply pagination on this page only using parsehub

Comment: The problem is not parse hub, it's the page that you are trying to scrape. Click on the next button in your browser and see what happens on the link you provided.

Answer (score 1):

The next button on the first page is broken so follow the instructions for [scraping a page with no next button](https://help.parsehub.com/hc/en-us/articles/221749647-Navigating-and-scraping-pages-with-no-Next-button-pagination-) or scrape the first page and the rest of the pages separately because the next button works on the following pages.